# How to create a local price index?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, real-estate, extrapolation

I have a set of real estate data; historic sales price, square meters, location (latitude, longitude), neighbourhood, city,  sold date and bunch of other features. I have used a boosting model to estimate the price of an individual house. I would like to estimate the price of a house 1 month ahead; but this requires extrapolating and something boosting is not capable of.

For this reason, I am trying to create inflation adjusted houses prices which will be fed into the boosting model. Old sale prices will therefore be inflation adjusted to 1 month ahead. This way I can capture inflation, and extrapolate over time. My objective is to create a separate model that can capture local changes in housing prices and extrapolate them forward. Essentially a price index.

I have aggregated the data at a city level by taking the median price per square meter for each month. The data exhibits strong AR characteristics. However, when I try this same approach on a neighbourhood (more local) level the AR characteristics disappear. I am unfortunately limited to 2 years of data.

What approach would you suggest to modelling a local price index that can be extrapolated with such a dataset? Kriging appears to be powerful, but is not made for extrapolation..

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this an ML practice problem?

https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-project-predicting-boston-house-prices-with-regression-b4e47493633d

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, its not. I want to create a local price index that can be used to make forecasts into the future.

Comment: If that's the case, you can look at how the FHFA defines HPI:

https://www.fhfa.gov/PolicyProgramsResearch/Research/Pages/HPI-Technical-Description.aspx

Comment: Old approach + based on repeat sales. I don't have repeat sales..

Comment: What is "historic sales price" then?

Not sure why you're being critical of an "old approach" that is still consistently used in the housing market. Take a look at Zillow's definition, might help you.

https://www.zillow.com/research/data/

Good luck with your problem.